# Set focus back to the proper textbox after autopostback function

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, autopostback

Now, this MAY look a duplicate, but it's not.
Every solution on the internet shows you how to get focus on the textbox that fired the event.

But what if the user presses tab? The textbox that should have focus is the next one.
So we do a workaround and focus on the textbox that have TabIndex higher than the one that fired the event.

But then what if the user presses Shift+tab?
Even worse: what if the user clicks on another random textbox?

This is the issue.
I don't think a code is required here, because it's a general solution to set focus on textboxes that have autopostback function.
If code is required, please ask in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

try, with SetFocus method on the server side

```
Page.SetFocus(IdOfControl);
```

Comment: And how exactly would I get the ID of the control that the user wants to be focused? The issue here is that the user can click in ANY texbox of the ENTIRE document, and the postback needs to keep the focus.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I fixed it using a hidden field where I store the last component that the user select(click or tab) and after the postback, it will set the focus back to this component.

Create hidden field in your page:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hiddenCurrentFocus" ClientIDMode="static"></asp:HiddenField>
```

Set the OnFocusIn in all the components where you wish to set the focus back. Example:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtConfirmTransitId" OnFocusIn="setFocus(this.name)" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Create a JS function to store the name of the component in that hidden field(I'm using jQuery here, but you can do it with plain JS as well):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFocus(x) {
        $("#hiddenCurrentFocus").val(x);
    }
</script>
```

Now finally on the backend, you will set the focus after the postback

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Set focus to the proper control
            var currentFocus = hiddenCurrentFocus.Value.ToString();
            if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentFocus))
            {
                Page.SetFocus(Page.FindControl(currentFocus));
            }
            
        }
    }
```

This as a similar solution to the one that Jason suggested in the post below, but I prefer to store it in a hidden field:

[Set focus back to the proper textbox after autopostback function (Page.SetFocus doesn't solve the issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383998/set-focus-back-to-the-proper-textbox-after-autopostback-function-page-setfocus)